# Professor has collection of $40$ issues of journal in $4$ boxes with $10$ issues per box.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Professor has collection of $40$ issues of journal in $4$ boxes with $10$ issues per box.
>
> How to distribute the journals if:
> $(a)$ each box is numbered
> $(b)$ boxes are identical

---

I thought of having total $40$ balls and then since the box are numbered, so choose $10$ out of $40$ in $40\choose 10$  for first box, then remaining 30 balls, choose 10 in $30 \choose  10$ for second box and so on for remaining two boxes.

So in total $$=\binom{40}{10}\binom{30}{10} \binom{20}{10} \binom{10}{10}$$

For the part (b) of the question, since I can relate it to problem of labelled balls and unlabelled boxes, and then finding Stirling number , But I don't understnad how do we go with the 10 balls in each boxes. I am stuck with part(b).

Comment: There is no specification on 40 issues, I hope they are distinguishable

Comment: I thought of having total $40$ balls and then since the box are numbered, so choose $10$ out of $40$ in $C(40,10)$ for first box, then remaining $30$ balls , choose $10$ in $C(30,10)$ for second box and so on for remaining two boxes. <br> So in total=$C(40,10)*C(30,10)*C(20,10)*C(10,10)$

Comment: That works for (a).  For (b) you could count how many ways of reordering  the identical boxes.

Comment: For the part (b) of the question, since I can relate it to probelm of labelled balls and unlabelled boxes, and then  finding stirling number , But I dont understnad how do we go with the 10 balls  in each boxes. Iam stuck with part(b)

Comment: Although I am a [fan of Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6460+stirling+number+of+the+second), I do not think you need them here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24563/discussion-between-user2016963-and-henry).

Answer (score 0):

You solved in *(a)* when boxes are numbered. If you want to don't keep ordering the boxes, you simply have to divide by the number of possible orderings of the boxes.

Therefore, for  *(b)*

$$=\binom{40}{10}\binom{30}{10}\binom{20}{10}\binom{10}{10}/4!$$